# What does the regular expression /[\[\]]/g means?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

javascript code:

```
 getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        console.log(name);
        let regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)");
        let results = regex.exec(url);
        console.log(results)
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
```

I an unable to understand what this code will print for name and results and what will it be returning.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is your friend

Comment: i dont think this is duplicate but thnx for the above reference site

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info - Requests to explain a regex pattern are duplicates of **What does this regex mean**